# How to correctly embed a test Rails application inside the gem that it tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rubygems

I have a small gem that I have created and a separate small Rails application that I use to test the gem.

I have been looking for information about how I could embed the test rails app inside the gem so it's packaged as one and so I can launch it to test the application.

I have currently got it inside the gem tree in a subdirectory of test. I can change to that subdirectory and run the app up ok, or I can run its tests with rake. But is this the correct way to do this ?

(in case it makes any difference, this gem and the small test app are for Rails 2.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a look at some other gems on github and what they do. Some probably don't need a full rails app, but devise, for instance has a barebones rails app embedded at /test/rails_app

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/test/rails_app

Comment: Thank you for that, it's exactly what I have done. The rails app isn't embedded into the gem tests but it's own tests are second level of testing that's easy to do. And the app can be started up for some interactive testing.